# How to predict y-value in multiple linear regression model?

Tags: python

I have an OLS model to estimate housing prices

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

model = sm.ols('np.log(price) ~ np.log(lotsize) + np.log(sqrft) + bdrms', data = df).fit()
```

I want to plug in the following values for the betas into the estimated equation which will predict y (price):

lotsize = 20000, sqrft = 2500, bdrms = 4

There's an elegant way to accomplish this in R and I'm trying to replicate this in Python but have had little luck so far:

My goal is to accomplish something like this in Python code to predict y-value

```
predictY <- predict.lm(linearModel, data.frame(lotsize = c(20000), sqrft = c(2500), bdrms = c(4)))
exp(predictY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Looks like the best way to do it is this in case anyone stumbles across my post:

```
p = model.get_prediction(pd.DataFrame([{"lotsize":20000,"sqrft": 2500, "bdrms": 4}]))
p.summary_frame()
```